# Monerod and wallet fully synced, not recognizing transactions made before the fork as valid

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, monerod, synchronization, balance, bulletproofs

Both wallet and CLI are showing the incorrect balance after many full blockchain rescans, trying with the CLI, same result, rescan from genesis block and arbitrary block numbers, same result.

Full balance was there before the fork, and after the fork, a few txns made well before the fork (1 week+) have been rejected which makes up a significant portion of my balance. I know the funds are still there but the wallet cannot "see" them.

x64 ubuntu 18.04, V0.13.0.3, monerod running with GUI on top

[image: gui terminal export ubuntu x64 18.04]

Comment: Any luck w/ resolving this issue?

Comment: No, not yet, Downloaded 13.0.4 and re synced the blockchain from scratch, full balance is not showing

Comment: Did you also run `rescan_bc` in the wallet thereafter?

Comment: Yes, did a rescan_bc in the CLI wallet and a full wallet refresh from genesis in the GUI. CLI does not show the errors like the GUI, but getting the same messages as above, and same balance across both wallets. There are about 5 or so txn pre fork not showing up, cause of above errors, and one transaction post fork which has shown up with no issues

Answer (score 1):

Your transaction has an ADDITIONAL_PUBKEYS tag in the tx_extra field. This means it was a transaction with at least two destinations, at least one of which was a subaddress.

These warnings mean that your wallet does not know how to interpret this ADDITIONAL_PUBKEYS tag. Therefore your wallet must be an older wallet version that does not support subaddresses. Please check that you're using the latest GUI wallet.

Comment: Thanks for your insight, I am using 13.0.2 for monerod and 13.0.3 for the GUI, I am re-syncing the blockchain from genesis to see if that helps