# Unrecognized TXN format, incorrect balance v0.13.0.4

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, monero-wallet-cli, monerod

[image]

this is the same error received in v0.13.0.3 GUI

txn extra has unsupported format

all transactions are pre fork by weeks, and is leading to an incorrect balance showing in my wallet.

Re synced the blockchain from scratch post fork. rescan_bc in CLI and refreshed the GUI from genesis, both showing the same incorrect balance after complete wallet refresh. monerod is fully synced and wallet is in sync with monerod.

linux x64, virtual machine, v0.13.0.4

this is my post on v0.13.0.3
[Monerod and wallet fully synced, not recognizing transactions made before the fork as valid](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/10429/monerod-and-wallet-fully-synced-not-recognizing-transactions-made-before-the-fo)

where can I submit a bug report?

Comment: Can you confirm: 1. That the transaction you're attempting to see in your wallet was sent to you at approx "2018-07-06 17:56:50" 2. Whether you recall if it could have been a transaction sent to multiple recipients (e.g. due to a mining pool paying out to multiple people in the same transaction) 3. whether you had used your wallet to send to multiple recipients within the same transaction

Comment: This is definitely a mainnet wallet, right?  Not testnet or stagenet?

Comment: 1) yes that is correct 2) It could have, It was a transaction from a very large exchange 3)They were transactions coming into my account 4) yes mainnet wallet, not testnet

Comment: This looks like a bug that was fixed in https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/4885. If this fixes it (it's in master, but not in a release yet), please tell us what exchange it is.

Answer (score 0):

I have a theory that I'm posting as an answer.

I think you clone and build monero yourself.  And I think you're using the same startup sequence to launch `monero-wallet-gui` as you did previously.  And I think what happened is you didn't realize that new builds are being put in a different directory hierarchy in the `/build` directory.  So when you launch `monero-wallet-gui`, your computer is using the `PATH` you previously set (`build/release/bin`), meaning you keep launching the old software.

Comment: sorry no, I am using the compiled binaries, and I am getting the v0.13.0.4 version number when running the GUI and CLI